# How to read NMEA message using GPSD?

Tags: 14.04, gps

I am trying to read NMEA messages via GPSD (http://www.catb.org/gpsd/), but I do not know how to do that.

I have a GPS antenna which connects to the u-blox M8 GNSS Evaluation Kit Timin (https://www.u-blox.com/en/product/evk-8evk-m8) and this Kit is connected to Ubuntu laptop.

In the Terminal window, when I type `lsusb`, it shows me the device successfully connect (for example: `Bus 001 Device 036: ID 1546:01a8 U-Blox AG`)

As I know when the GPS receive a signal, it should be putting NMEA messages out in each port, and should be mounted by TTYACM0.

The Laptop also installed NTP (Network Time Protocol)

My questions are:

- What does the GPSD do with that?
- What can the GPSD log these messages?
- How to configure GPSD to set NMEA messages from the u-blox USB port?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/891662/why-does-cgps-s-give-me-no-results/891719#891719

Answer (score 1):

Read `man gpsd`. It says, in part:

```
Client applications will communicate with gpsd via a TCP/IP port, 2947
by default). Both IPv4 and IPv6 connections are supported and a client
may connect via either.
```

Comment: if I receive these message : gpsd:INFO: launching (Version 3.11)
gpsd:ERROR: can't bind to IPv4 port gpsd, Address already in use
gpsd:ERROR: maybe gpsd is already running!
gpsd:ERROR: can't bind to IPv6 port gpsd, Address already in use
gpsd:ERROR: maybe gpsd is already running!
gpsd:INFO: command sockets creation failed, netlib errors -1, -1.  what should I do?

Comment: You should not use comments to ask a second question. Other people with a problem like "How to read NMEA message using GPSD?" can find this answer through the Search box. If one were to answer a second question buried in a comment, AskUbuntu's indexing would not find it.  See [ask] "How to Ask"

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate this comes a bit late but providing information for completeness and reference.

gpsd uses its own communication protocol and doesn't provide NMEA output by default (though it is easy by passing a couple commands). If you have tools that can require NMEA but do not under gpsd, you need a translator. See below link for one:

https://github.com/itemir/rpi_boat_utils/tree/master/gpsd2nmea