# Why does "cgps -s" give me no results?

Tags: 14.04, gps

I have a device U-blox EVK-M8T which can read NMEA messages. I followed the instructions from [this page](https://bigdanzblog.wordpress.com/2015/01/18/connecting-u-blox-neo-6m-gps-to-raspberry-pi/).

Everything is fine, but when I typed `cgps -s` to see what time, PRN, ELev, Azim, etc., I expected this:

```
Time:-------2015-01-18T01:25:41.000Z---||PRN:   Elev:  Azim:  SNR:  Used: |
|    Latitude:    00.0000   N               ||   2    06    312    00      Y   |
|    Longitude:  000.0000   W               ||   3    24    182    28      Y   |
|    Altitude:   582.0 m                    ||   6    07    271    00      Y   |
|    Speed:      0.1 kph                    ||   7    39    254    26      Y   |
|    Heading:    0.0 deg (true)             ||   8    33    059    35      Y   |
|    Climb:      n/a                        ||   9    65    302    29      Y   |
|    Status:     3D FIX (7 secs)            ||  10    35    301    37      Y   |
|    Longitude Err:   +/- 1 m               ||  16    56    082    43      Y   |
|    Latitude Err:    +/- 2 m               ||  20    46    223    34      Y   |
|    Altitude Err:    +/- 5 m               ||  23    80    110    40      Y   |
|    Course Err:      n/a                   ||  27    10    116    22      Y   |
|    Speed Err:       +/- 18 kph            ||                                 |
|    Time offset:     0.597                 ||                                 |
|    Grid Square:     DN17hq
```

But I received no results:

```
│    Time:       n/a                        ││PRN:   Elev:  Azim:  SNR:  Used: │
│    Latitude:   n/a                        ││                                 │
│    Longitude:  n/a                        ││                                 │
│    Altitude:   n/a                        ││                                 │
│    Speed:      n/a                        ││                                 │
│    Heading:    n/a                        ││                                 │
│    Climb:      n/a                        ││                                 │
│    Status:     NO FIX (0 secs)            ││                                 │
│    Longitude Err:   n/a                   ││                                 │
│    Latitude Err:    n/a                   ││                                 │
│    Altitude Err:    n/a                   ││                                 │
│    Course Err:      n/a                   ││                                 │
│    Speed Err:       n/a                   ││                                 │
│    Time offset:     n/a                   ││                                 │
│    Grid Square:     n/a                   ││                                 │
```

Does anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments...

- open TCP port 2947 in your firewall
- in `terminal`, edit `/etc/default/gpsd`

  - `gksudo gedit /etc/default/gpsd`
  - change `DEVICES=""` to `DEVICES="/dev/ttyACM0"`
  - save and quit gedit
  - `sudo systemctl restart gpsd`

gpsmon, cgps, and xgps will now work properly.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55172/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-why-does-cgps-s-give-me-no-results).